# Basic Usage of TableTools example not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabletools

In my Visual Studio project, I copied the exact code here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html

---

I saved the two css files in my project as `style1.css`, `style2.css`.

I saved the three js files as `script1.js`, `script2.js`, `script3.js`.

Then, I had my `custom.js` file as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip'
    } );
} );
```

Finally, my `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--inserted exact copy of html table-->
</body>
```

---

From what I understand, the code off that page should work as is.
However, it doesn't seem to be working at all.

- No formatting whatsoever
- Cannot see the "copy", "csv"... buttons

How do I arrange all my files/code so that it works?

I am fairly new at this; any help is appreciated!

Comment: I added a reference to jquery 2.1.1 but that did not fix it

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: Oh, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". But I included jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to jquery library and TableTools plugins. On the page that shows the example, under the Javascript section you will see text explaining that you need these three libraries.

Place this before your other js files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did; the last link in the "CSS" tab and the last link in the "JS" tab are the two files for the TableTools plugin. I included these as my `style2.css` and `script3.js`.

Comment: The jquery and tabletools script files need to be above any other js files. In the code you pasted, `script3.js` is last. Should be first.

Comment: It's also important that the source code inside your `script3.js` file goes `jquery`, `jquery.dataTables` then `dataTables.tableTools` in that order.